# Numpy: Most efficent way to find elements that have at least one zero adjacent to it ("edges")

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have a numpy array like this:

```
np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
          [1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
          [2, 2, 2, 1, 0],
          [3, 3, 3, 2, 1]])
```

How can I get the indices of the values that have a zero orthogonaly adjacent to it?
By orthogonaly I mean it wouldn't look at diagonally adjacent items.
For the example the output should be:

```
np.array([[1, 1], [2, 0], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4]])
```

Comment: Is your array really 5x5?

Comment: @Mark Setchell no it's actually 3d and a lot larger, I was just using it as an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there something wrong with the obvious approach ?

```
mask = arr == 0
out = np.zeros(mask.shape, dtype='bool')

out[:-1] = out[:-1] | mask[1:]
out[1:] = out[1:] | mask[:-1]
out[:,:-1] = out[:,:-1] | mask[:,1:]
out[:,1:] = out[:,1:] | mask[:,:-1]

np.argwhere(out & (arr!=0))
```

Comment: Yes it does, thank you, it just wasn't obvoius to me. My method involved looping over the list, calculating the neighbors, and adding the indices if the neighbors contained a 0

Comment: Oh sure. I sometimes totally forget that loops are the normal approach and only people having their mind twisted by numpy think in arrays. I am glad it helped though.